Ubuntu CodeBlocks move windows around
Story: I am trying to migrate to using Ubuntu (I am aware of the existence of other distros, that is not the focus of the question) and I wanted to install CodeBlocks on it (I am aware that there might be "better" IDEs, it is not the focus of the question). After successfully installing it I tried to debug a simple program, but the watches tab can only be resized, not moved around (It is in a deranging spot). I tried to move other tabs around but the same thing happened, they can only be resized.
I tried to find a solution online for about 2 hours. I would really appreciate some help.
Summary: I can only resize tabs in CodeBlocks on Ubuntu, but cannot move them around. I am asking how to move them, simple hold click and drag has no effect.
Photo:


Could you please try a newer Nightly Build?
I think that may be caused by wxWidgets' dock window, maybe this post is like your problem.
